# Symfony 4 - change public folder path (No input file specified. error)

Tags: symfony, controller, public

I'm new to Symphony, I'm updating Symfony 3 app into Symfony 4.4.
App I work on has structure:

- app/public - which seems to be default public folder in Symfony 4
- app/web/frontend - which was my public folder in Symfony 3

I get error:
No input file specified.

Which seems to be regarding missing front controller. After updating to Symfony 4 my public folder changed, therefore /public/index.php is not found.

Is there a way i can change default behavior in Symfony 4.4 to change my public folder back to app/web/frontend?

I tried this, but it doesn't work.
https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/configuration/override_dir_structure.html#override-the-public-directory

Comment: There are actually a number of directory changes from the older Symfony 2/3 style to Symfony 4.  'doesn't work' does not really help much when trouble shooting.  It is possible to use different directory layouts but it requires a bit of expertise.  There is no simple setting to change.  Might need to invest some time in learning the framework.

Comment: Thank you for your response. What I meant by this solution not working:

Comment: Thank you for your response. What I meant by this solution not working: https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/configuration/override_dir_structure.html#override-the-public-directory is that it doesn't change the public folder path as far as I can say. I keep getting 'No input file specified'. I changed my app/public to app/publicc and changed composer.json "extra.public-dir" to "publicc". This should work now, because I manually copied files to publicc folder, but it doesn't. Can you recommend good place to start learning about framework or some specific functionality that I should know?

Comment: When I change it back to app/public and remove extra.public-dir it works, but manually copying files seems like very 'dirty' solution and something that will cause problems in the future.